# How can add Preg Match to Match String with dot, Apostrophes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I make Preg Match to Search Strings With `.`, `'`,`"` and `#`? I tried used the following code but it doesnt work if the string contains `.`, `' .

`(preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($txtsize,'/')."\b/i", $row['ItemDescription'])`

Using the above code i couldnt get this on Search  `31X15.50-15 12 PLY TRAXION HF2` or `31X15.50` or `1.75"X11.500"` or

Thank you

Comment: What is `$txtsize`? Better you show some example inputs and expected matches

Comment: @anubhava contains the value in the textbox `$txtsize = $_REQUEST['search_by_size']`;

Comment: Is `31X15.50-15 12 PLY TRAXION HF2`  `$row['ItemDescription']` or `$txtsize`? Which ever it is please post the other variables value.

Comment: @chris85 that is `$row['ItemDescription']`

Comment: Okay, than what is `$txtsize`? Not `$_REQUEST['search_by_size']` but the actual value.

Comment: @chris85 Its a variable containing the value in `search_by_size` text box. text box i use to enter search keys.  `$txtsize = $_REQUEST['search_by_size']`

Comment: That still tells me nothing about the value. All I know is that your regex is `\bSOMETHING_ESCAPED\b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^[a-z.'"#]+$
      ^--- Put all the characters you consider valid within the character class
           define as [...]
```

Graphically is more understandable...

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM7wY2/1)**

You can use this code

```
$re = "/^[a-z.'\"#]+$/mi"; // Notice insensitive flag: i
$str = "YOUR STRING HERE"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

However, if you want to pass these strings:

```
31X15.50-15 12 PLY TRAXION HF2 
31X15.50
```

You'll have to allow spaces, hyphens and numbers in your regex, so you'll have to use:

```
^[a-z.'"# 0-9-]+$
      ↑
      | below the code
      |
$re = "/^[a-z.'\"#]+$/mi";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fede I updated my code as $re = "/^[a-z.'\"#]+$/mi"; $str = $_REQUEST['search_by_size']; and Preg Match looks like elseif (($str!="") && preg_match($re, $str, $row['ItemDescription']) || ($row['ItemDescription']==$str)){...display result...}. But no luck what did i do wrong?

Comment: @Aaron I don't know what values you have in your variables, I think you should troubleshoot it with a debugger